# Possible to combine wipe transition with Transform zoom effect strip?

Tags: transforms, effects

Wondering if it's possible to combine a wipe transition where one clip is normal zoom and the other clip is zoomed in with a transform effect strip. How do i do this / is it possible?

Comment: I haven't had time to try this but you might try to combine the zoom transform strip with it's video in a 'Meta' strip, then do the wipe between the 2nd video and Meta strip.  Failing this, setup a plane in the 3D window and do it all 'physically' with keyframed animation.  Use the camera to produce the final render.  More details available if you're unfamiliar with animation.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly!